# Make form button/text field same height in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, forms, height

I have the following css and html (drilled down to the essentials. The full code with additional styles can be found here: I have this css I pasted on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BwhvX/ , this is however enough to reproduce the problem)

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: none;
}
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}

#search .text, #search .button {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

html:

```
<form method="post" id="search" action="">
    <p><input type="text" class="text" value="" name="suche"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Suchen"></p>
</form>
```

this is how firefox renders:

## [image: nice looking]

this is how chrome renders:

[image: bad looking]

i want the two form elements to have the same height in all browsers. looks to me like some default style is applied, that i manually need to reset like i did for firefox in this example.
in chrome developer tools one has height 16 and one height 17 px but i am not able to see where it comes from, its just calculated. the applied styles (that are shown to me) are the same.

Comment: seems like i fixed it for ff and chrome by adding line-height: 16px !important; to .button .. however i don't understand. then i would expect the button to be 1 px heigher

Answer (score 18, accepted):

change:

```
*{
    line-height: normal !important;
}
```

or add something like:

```
input[type="submit"], input[type="text"] {
    line-height:normal !important;
}
```

don't ask why)

and. safari need special fixes. but looks well

Comment: Sorry, I must ask. Why?

Comment: +1 such a simple solution where others have huge workarounds.  Nicely done.  It turns out the `button` element inherits (of calculates in Chrome) the `line-height` from its parent where as `input` is set to `normal`.  [Discussed on GitHub necolas/normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/377).

Answer (score 11):

I found this in [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) that solved it for me:

```
// Removes inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try By giving

```
.text{
 border:0px;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually one of these below has worked for me in the past using firefox browser.

```
 vertical-align: bottom;
  vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify height instead of line-height, they will render correctly. height behaves well cross-browser; line-height does not.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with firefox, setting line-height:normal didn’t help. Setting identitcal padding values on both, the input and button element, helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 has the [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property. Setting it's value to *border-box*, you tell the browser that the element's border-width and padding should be included into element's height, and then may easily set the height itself:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 15px;
}
```

This works for html *select* elements as well.