# css input align with button

Tags: forms, input, css, alignment

**IE 6**

[image]

**FireFox, Chrome, IE 8**

[image]

i cant get the button to align the same for all the browsers.. is there a hack for doing this alignment?

```
input, button {
   float: left;
   height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? This should ensure all your margins and padding is zeroed out: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: You can find solution here : - [Make form button/text field same height in all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483279/make-form-button-text-field-same-height-in-all-browsers) - [Equal height inputs and buttons](http://christophzillgens.com/en/articles/equal-height-input-and-button-elements-in-firefox-and-safari)

Comment: If none of the solutions below work, you always have the option of using hacks to tweak the appearance for the trouble browsers while not affecting the code for the more modern browsers.

Comment: how? can you paste a link of example or something..

Answer (score 6):

```
vertical-align: bottom;
 vertical-align: top;
```

Usually one of these works.....(firefox)