# CSS - Exact same height and alignment of button and input text box

Tags: css, forms, cross-browser

I need to have a button and a tex box sitting next to each other and they have to align up perfectly as if one is bigger than the other then it will be instantly noticeable.

Usually I wouldnt bother about small differences between browsers, but these two input are sitting in a very prominent position on every page and are a big feature of the site so they have to align perfectly in all major browsers and zoom levels.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this.

Just as a quick example of what i am trying to achieve: the new google homepage.  After starting to type the autocomplete kicks in and the search box is moved to the top with a blue button perfectly aligned to the text box.  It works perfectly cross browser but its marked up in a table.  Does that suggest that this may be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Hi - have tried lots of different things, i am trying to keep any extra markup to a minium so ideally it would be a form with a label, an input box and a button with a type of submit.

Comment: You might also try asking this on the new [User Experience beta site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @David, yes: but mark-up are you *already* using? What are we working with; seeing what you've got already helps us provide better answers and to better help you.

Comment: If you provide a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) with example code, and state exactly which browsers/versions you need the height/alignment to be consistent in, I'll give it a go.

Comment: If the issue is Firefox, this answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734594/970551

Answer (score 26):

I'd suggest trying to style the parent element of the `input`/`button` pairing (a `fieldset`, in my example) in order to give a common `font-size`, and `font-family`, then using `em` measurements for styling dimensions/padding/margins for the child elements. Ideally styling all the child elements with the same CSS.

Given the following mark-up:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="something">A label for the text-input</label>
        <input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
        <button>It's a button!</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'd suggest something *similar*, but adapted to your particular design, to the following CSS:

```
fieldset {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

label, input, button {
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
    /* the following ensures they're all using the same box-model for rendering */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box; /* or `border-box` */
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QKLUH/3/).

---

Following the clarification that this is to replicate/reproduce the style of Google's adjoined text-input/submit button:

```
fieldset {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-width: 0;
}

label, input, button {
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.3em 0.4em;
    margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
    background-color: #fff;
}

input {
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0.6em 0 0 0.6em;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ffa;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,210,0.5);
}
button {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0.6em 0.6em 0;
    background-color: #aef;
}
button:active,
button:focus {
    background-color: #acf;
    outline: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QKLUH/4/).

Albeit the above works fine in Chromium 12.x and Opera 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.04), Firefox seems to show an extra pixel or two in the latter demonstration.

Comment: thanks very much for your time on this but you are experiencing exactly the same issues as me.  It simply has to be perfect in every major browser given the prominence of the form elements.  Im a fairly experienced developer so know how difficult it is to get form elements to behave and can do so to a certain extent, its just that these need to be 100% prefectly aligned at all times.

Comment: Wow is that the simplest possible CSS solution to the problem *"a button and a tex box sitting next to each other and they have to align up perfectly"*.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is very bulletproof:

http://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/pbkyoJ

On both elements just use:

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 15px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

And use "normalize.css" - that's all. Looks good on iPhone, too:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I've been pulling my hair for hours trying to achieve this. After a lot of research and experimentation, here's the recipe for solving the OP's problem in (at least contemporary versions of) Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari:

1. Use the same CSS regarding the box model for all types of nodes you need to align (button, input, select);
2. **DO** specify the border explicitly (or at least its width);
3. **DO NOT** specify the height explicitly.

Yes, that's all there is to it. Here's the most minimalist CSS that produces the desired results:

```
select, input, button {
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

If you need further styling, feel free to add color, padding and margins -- everything will work out fine. But, no matter what you do, do NOT specify the height explicitly. That's the only deal breaker, because each browser calculates the height differently; some will leave an extra pixel or two above the select and not the button, some will leave them above the button and not the select, and some will work as expected.

For the record, Chrome seems to be the most consistent in this regard (that is, if you do specify the height) -- but then again, who cares.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback -- but if you're going to give feedback, please explain in a couple of words what exactly is not working (which type of element on what browser).

Comment: Great hint. To get exactly the same height on different browsers/platforms in needed to specify the height for inputs and selects (in em of course) but not for buttons and links (a elements).

Comment: Can I specify padding? em's?

Answer (score 2):

In 2019 you want to be using CSS Grid for your forms even if they just have one input and one button.

This saves a lot of pain.

I have lots going on with my working example so I will not post a working example here. Instead, here are the things you need to know.

The outer container can be the `form`, CSS for this being `display: grid; grid-template-rows: 2em; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;`

The input should have a label which I will assume is set to be hidden. So the CSS for the input has `grid-column: 1; height: 100%;` the button has `grid-column: 2; height: 100%`

You are going to do your own things with margins, backgrounds, paddings, borders, border radius and such like.

The crucial thing of getting the button to line up with the input is done with the grid row having a fixed height in ems or another sensible responsive friendly unit and the input and button being set to a height of 100%.

I did not find any of the above answers to result in as succinct and manageable code as the CSS Grid option which works for me on Firefox, Chrome and a Webkit based browser.

Note that if using CSS Grid then you need precisely zero `div` elements in your form, however, if using fieldsets you may need to set them to `display: content` as CSS Grid does not work with `fieldset`.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked many sources in WEB how to do it the best, cross-browser, theme-independent. I hope I have solution, bit it is not 100% (it needs to be trimmed by vertical CSS padding). My problem was **to have label and text-input with the same width and compact**.

Wished result:
[image: Wished result]
The solution I found by several experiments is described by my blog: http://vasvadev.blogspot.cz/2013/02/css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of.html

Solution
CSS:

```
div.lf-ui-label {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
div.lf-ui-label + input.lf-ui-form-item {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: #2b55a8 !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-width: 0px;
}
input.lf-ui-form-item {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 4px 7px 4px 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none 0px;
  outline: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="padding:10px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px;">
   <div class="lf-ui-label" 
    style="width:25%; padding-left: 10px;">Field text 14px&nbsp;</div><input 
    class="lf-ui-form-item" type="text" id="fr" name="fr" value="some value"      style="width:71%" />
</div>
<div  style="padding:10px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px;">
  Field text <input class="lf-ui-form-item" type="text" value="some other value"/>
</div>
```

My experimental code is shared by JSFIDDLE: [css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of.html](http://jsfiddle.net/afrbx/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to solve this for days and every solution is not whole, and not working in different browsers.

I find that this code do the work:

```
float: left;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
height: 33px;
```

I have updated Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p9maozk2/

Answer (score 1):

Your other option is to use **Bootstrap**. I solve this issue by assigning class "[input-group](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#basic-example)" to the **div** that wraps the input and the button/s.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to achieve pixel perfect dimensions in a cross-browser way, the very first thing you should do is consider implementing a CSS reset. I prefer [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), but there are others you can find from googling.

The CSS reset is really fundamental in normalizing cross-browser differences (especially when dealing with forms).

Comment: @David Your off to a good start then. The next logical step would be either implementing @madflow's recommendation of using IE conditional classes, or serving up alternate stylesheets for IE (again using conditional classes). However, if you want any further guidance or help you will need to update your question with code and let us know what problems you are having with specific browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For IE: You can style things differently by using conditional stylesheets:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7e" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So you would write:

```
.ie6 .my-button-class {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who's trying to do it now I found that this solution seems to work. Try adding :

```
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
```

to your current `css` on both elements which will still leave them slightly misaligned, and then play around with the top padding in the misaligned element. I found that :

```
padding-top: 2px;
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a vertically aligned `input` + `button` combo, with no margin between elements (thanks to `font-size:0px`), and where the input field does not increase in vertical height when selected; here font-size controls vertical height, whereas line-height would cause vertical misalignment.

html

```
<div class="emailbuttonparent">
<input type="email" class="emailaddr" placeholder="email" />
<input type="button" value="Get Started" />
</div>
```

css

```
.emailbuttonparent {
    font-size: 0;
}

select, input, button {
    display:inline-block;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}


    input[type="email"]:focus {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        color: #fff;
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been a good decade or so, and I wasn't satisfied with anything already posted, so I spent a couple of days to figure out a solution for this problem that works perfectly in *at least* following browser versions:

- Chrome >= 4
- Firefox >= 4
- Safari >= 3
- Opera >= 11
- IE >= 9
- Edge 97

**HTML**

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text">
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container,
#container input,
#container button {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: table;
}

#container input,
#container button {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  height: ...; /* e.g. 2.8em */
  font-size: ...; /* e.g. 14px */
  border: ...; /* e.g. 1px solid red */
}
```

Aside from above bare-minimum required CSS rules, you can change most other usual style-rules like `color`, `background-color`, `box-shadow`, `border-radius`, etc. however you like. However, there are some things that could restrict your styling options a bit. For example, you should avoid adding/adjusting `padding`, especially top/bottom, as it might clip text (use `height` / `width` rules instead if possible).

Answer (score -1):

Use a background div with an image for the input. That is much easier to keep consistent. Also, absolute positioning is good for this type of situation.

edit: I wrote this answer 5 years ago, there are better ways now.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.sdiv {
padding-top: 33px;
padding-left: 33px;
height: 123px;
border: 1px dotted red;
border-radius: 7px;
background-color: Black;
}

.sbtn {
float:left;
height:24px;
width: 24px;
padding: 3px 0 0 0;
border:none;
margin-top: 14px;
background-color: white;
}

.stxt {
width: 180px;
height:22px;
float:left;
border:none;
padding-left:3px;
margin-top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sdiv">
<form action="/">

<input class="stxt" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="">

<button class="sbtn" type="submit">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="icon" viewBox="0 0 18 18" width="18" height="18">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 12.864 11.32 h -0.813 l -0.288 -0.277 A 6.66 6.66 0 0 0 13.38 6.69 a 6.69 6.69 0 1 0 -6.69 6.69 a 6.66 6.66 0 0 0 4.354 -1.617 l 0.278 0.288 v 0.813 L 16.467 18 L 18 16.467 l -5.136 -5.146 Z m -6.174 0 a 4.625 4.625 0 0 1 -4.632 -4.63 A 4.625 4.625 0 0 1 6.69 2.058 a 4.625 4.625 0 0 1 4.63 4.632 a 4.625 4.625 0 0 1 -4.63 4.63 Z" />
</svg>
</button>

</form>
</div>
```

All excellent answers! But none were really what I was looking for...

I got more satisfaction from more straightforward approach: