# CSS - button and text input don't line up when containing Japanese text

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I want an adjacent text input and button to line up perfectly. I'm specifically targeting Chrome, although it would be extra nice if it worked in all modern browsers.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6726350/2167882) almost works, although it still doesn't line up right in Firefox. However, if I enter Japanese text into the button, the height gets offset slightly, even if I enter Japanese text into the text input as well.

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN', 'ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3', Meiryo, メイリオ, Osaka, 'MS PGothic', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

label, input, button {
  font-size: inherit;
  height: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="This works" />
    <button>just fine</button>
  </div>
</form>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="あ This" />
    <button>あ doesn't line up!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88nv388k/))
On Chrome 54.0.2840.99, results in this:
[image: Bad alignment]

Funnily enough, they line up perfectly in IE 11.

Is there a way to align these perfectly in Chrome, and preferably also in Firefox and Safari? The slight difference is driving me crazy.

Comment: try adding  `vertical-align: middle;` in css

Comment: Maybe reduce the font-size slightly, of the japanese text only, in the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what I think happens here:

1. The default vertical alignment for inline elements is `vertical-align: baseline`
2. When using different fonts, the *baseline* alignment can cause issues as the font metrics like *ascenders* or *descenders* can affect the alignment issues in some browser versions.

[image]

Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))

My guess is, therefore, `vertical-align: middle` will save your day if you use other fonts.

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN', 'ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3', Meiryo, メイリオ, Osaka, 'MS PGothic', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

label, input, button {
  font-size: inherit;
  height: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.1em 0.1em;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="This works" />
    <button>just fine</button>
  </div>
</form>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="あ This" />
    <button>あ doesn't line up!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```