# Despite looking at several similar questions, I am still unable to style an Input element and Submit form the same

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24);
 background-size: cover;
 display: inline-block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 clear: right;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.home{
 text;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 top: 15px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color:black;
}

.navList {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 30px;
}

.navLi {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.navLi a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.searchBox {
    margin-top: 90px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.searchSubmit {
 background: url("magnifying-glass.png");
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <!-- ========= START OF NAVBAR ======= -->
  <div class="nav">
   <a href="" class="home">Greg's List</a>
   <ul class="navList" title="navigation">
    <li class="navLi"><a href="">Post</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="">Account</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- ========= END OF NAVBAR ======= -->

  <!-- ========= Search Box Start======= -->
  <div class="searchBox">
   <label>Search Jobs</label>
   <div class="searchInputBox">
    <form>
     <input class="searchInput" type="search" placeholder="Search Software Jobs">
     <button class="searchSubmit" type="submit"></button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ========= Search Box End======= -->
 </div>
</body>
```

[There are several questions that are the exact same. This is one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726135/css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of-button-and-input-text-box)

I have an image that is 30 pixels by 30 pixels. I am using this image as the background for a submit button. I need to increase the height of the input element so that it is the same height as the submit button, 30 pixels.

For some reason, I haven't been able to increase the height of the input element using the height property. I am using inline-block so that can't be it.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: how would using a style tag be different than using CSS?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. Give `vertical-align:middle` to `input` and `button`.

```
form input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.searchSubmit {
  background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/search-16.png") no-repeat 0 0; /*this image url is only for refrence*/
  background-position: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;  
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```css
.nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.home{ 
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:black;
}

.navList {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}

.navLi {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.navLi a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.searchBox {
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
form input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.searchSubmit {
  background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/search-16.png") no-repeat 0 0; /*this image url is only for refrence*/
  background-position: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;  
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- ========= START OF NAVBAR ======= -->
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="" class="home">Greg's List</a>
      <ul class="navList" title="navigation">
        <li class="navLi"><a href="">Post</a></li>
        <li class="navLi"><a href="">Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ========= END OF NAVBAR ======= -->

    <!-- ========= Search Box Start======= -->
    <div class="searchBox">
      <label>Search Jobs</label>
      <div class="searchInputBox">
        <form>
          <input class="searchInput" type="search" placeholder="Search Software Jobs">
          <button class="searchSubmit" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ========= Search Box End======= -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The input element doesn't result in being the same size and shape as the form submit button. Both need to be rounded rectangular objects with the button being a square.

Comment: Must be a browser issue then, no?

Comment: Then give height to input.

Comment: Not sure what bootstrap is, but i've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: can you provide any screenshot how you want...?

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: What did you change exactly? I had been doing .searchInput{height:30px;}

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code. You can change the 'height' property of the button.

**CSS**

```
.nav {
height: 60px;
background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24);
background-size: cover;
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
float: left;
clear: right;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.home{
text;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 15px;
font-size: 1.5em;
color:black;
}

.navList {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
}

.navLi {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.navLi a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.searchBox {
margin-top: 90px;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 100px;
}

.searchSubmit {
background: url("magnifying-glass.png");
height: 20px;
width: 30px;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- ========= START OF NAVBAR ======= -->
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="" class="home">Greg's List</a>
        <ul class="navList" title="navigation">
            <li class="navLi"><a href="">Post</a></li>
            <li class="navLi"><a href="">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ========= END OF NAVBAR ======= -->

    <!-- ========= Search Box Start======= -->
    <div class="searchBox">
        <label>Search Jobs</label>
        <div class="searchInputBox">
            <form>
                <input class="searchInput" type="search" 
                  placeholder="Search Software Jobs">
                <button class="searchSubmit" type="submit"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ========= Search Box End======= -->
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I definitely thought about changing the 'height' property.

Comment: Must be a browser issue then, no?

Comment: I've edited my question to make my desired output more clear

Answer (score 0):

Why not? There are few default browser CSS you need to overwrite to achieve this.

Try the css below:

```
input.searchInput {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

button.searchSubmit {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    height: 30px;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.nav {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24);
 background-size: cover;
 display: inline-block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 clear: right;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.home{
 text;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 top: 15px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color:black;
}

.navList {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 30px;
}

.navLi {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.navLi a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.searchBox {
    margin-top: 90px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.searchSubmit {
 background: url("magnifying-glass.png");
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 background-size: 100%;
}

input.searchInput {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

button.searchSubmit {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <!-- ========= START OF NAVBAR ======= -->
  <div class="nav">
   <a href="" class="home">Greg's List</a>
   <ul class="navList" title="navigation">
    <li class="navLi"><a href="">Post</a></li>
    <li class="navLi"><a href="">Account</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- ========= END OF NAVBAR ======= -->

  <!-- ========= Search Box Start======= -->
  <div class="searchBox">
   <label>Search Jobs</label>
   <div class="searchInputBox">
    <form>
     <input class="searchInput" type="search" placeholder="Search Software Jobs">
     <button class="searchSubmit" type="submit"></button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ========= Search Box End======= -->
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The input element doesn't result in being the same size and shape as the form submit button. Both need to be rounded rectangular objects with the button being a square.