# IE input placeholder vertical alignment

Tags: css

I have an input field with placeholder text but not able to get it vertically center aligned. It works correctly in Chrome but not in IE 11. In IE it is aligned to the bottom.

Below is what I have at the moment,

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I tried `text-align: middle` but didn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Exact same height and alignment of button and input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726135/css-exact-same-height-and-alignment-of-button-and-input-text-box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put line-height:normal; for all inputs. it will take normal line-height.

Comment: Thanks, although this seemed to help a bit the main problem in my code was padding.