# CSS fixing of search box

Tags: css

Height of `submit field` is slightly smaller than the `text input` field. How do I fix it?

HTML code:

```
<form name="searchBox" id="searchBox" action="#" method="post"> <input type="text" name="query" id="query"/> 
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Search"/> </form>
```

CSS code:

```
form input[type="text"] {
height: 28px;
width: 300px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 15px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
height: 28px;
width: 80px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some example html code?

Comment: Can we see the live site, there might be something else interfering with your elements.

Comment: `<form name="searchBox" id="searchBox" action="#" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="query" id="query"/>
     <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Search"/>
    </form>`

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the height? make it 1px smaller/bigger and maybe it will look the same?

Comment: A similar question has been answered here in stackoverflow. [Make form button/text field same height in all browsers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483279/make-form-button-text-field-same-height-in-all-browsers

Comment: That fix does not work in mijn jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/yk56z/

If you give both inputs `height: 3px`, the submit button has a height of zero...

Answer (score 2):

you can increase or decrease `height` of the text/submit fields to align properly.
**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/2DdA3/